# how do I map a key in eclipse to run the project run configuration?

Tags: java, eclipse, scala, run-configuration

I created a new eclipse project with a new run configuration. This configuration is visible on the drop down menu for run configurations and has a 1 on it. How do I assign a Key to run exacty this configuration?

The problem I have is, that I use eclipse to write scala, and the hotkey "Run as Scala" does only work if my editor has the file with the main class opened (WTF). On all other files I get the error message "Editor does not contain a main type" without any further information. So I created a run configuration, where I specified the Main file, but now I don't know how to start this configuration without touching the mouse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

works best Alt+R then T then 1.

Answer (score 1):

The hot key to run something is Ctrl-F11.

Comment: I mapped already F9 to "Run as Scala application", but that doesn't help, because it only works if my editor has the main method opend, otherwise I get  "Editor does not contain a main type". Can't tell you why. So I made my own run configuration where I manually specified my main class. But how do I start that with a keyboard shortcut?

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [Shortcut for selecting run configuration in Eclipse IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28926894/shortcut-for-selecting-run-configuration-in-eclipse-ide) which said to use ALT+R, N, and then type a name, which shows Run Configurations for me.

**Best option:**

- Assign (bind) a shortcut via   Window > Preferences, General > Keys
- The command to select is **"Run..."**

(I added this answer because for me the accepted one shows Run Menu, then T is for Terminate, nothing to do with Run Configs)